# Uploading an image with Retrofit returns a 200 OK but with 0-byte body

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit

What the title says. The problem only happens when using Retrofit. Uploads using Postman or Android's  HTTPURLConnection+DataOutputStream work fine and return the json body from the REST api.

Here's a working request/response log from Postman:

```
  Remote Address:   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 Request URL:  [ --- secret --- ]
 Request Method:POST Status Code:200 OK Response Headers  (8) Request
 Headers view source Accept:*/* Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6,gl;q=0.4
 Cache-Control:no-cache Connection:keep-alive Content-Length:11519
 Content-Type:multipart/form-data;
 boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGlChAAe9WOKlPy2D
 Cookie:laravel_session= [...] Host: [secret]

 Request Payload
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryGlChAAe9WOKlPy2D Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload[]"; filename="avatar.png" Content-Type:
 image/png
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryGlChAAe9WOKlPy2D--
```

Here's the Retrofit version:

```
 ----> HTTP POST http://xxxxxxx

 Accept: application/json
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data
 Content-Length: 9094
 --1d87e0b7-bf5d-4034-b20b-48155a5dee2a
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload[]" filename="picSuggestion.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg Content-Length: 8846
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
---> END HTTP (9094-byte body)
 <--- HTTP 200 http://xxxxxxxx/api/uploads/?api=true&token=xxxx(1240ms)
 : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 Date: Fri, 28 Aug 2015 13:11:20 GMT
 Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
 Set-Cookie: laravel_session=xxxxxxx; path=/; httponly
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 X-Android-Received-Millis: 1440767479264
 X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
 X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1440767478578
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
 <--- END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

We tried a bunch of Retrofit service and interceptor configurations without success, but here's the latest one we tried

```
requestInterceptor2 = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade request) {

            request.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data" );
            request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json" );
            request.addQueryParam("key", API_KEY);

        }
    };

 @Multipart
    @POST("/api/uploads/")
    void uploadImage(@Part(value = "upload[]", encoding = "binary") TypedFile payload, @Query("api") boolean api, @Query("token") String token, Callback<uploadImagePoiResultVO> cb);
```

Comment: can you please send me your request data for api call

Comment: Hi, what request data do you want? We uploaded the image using both retrofit and Postman and we posted both request dumps above, let us know what else you need, thanks.